# E-commerce php issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have in the database all products that can be added to `cart` and when I add one in the cart these remain there .. I want to do that any user who visit the site, see the empty cart and when you close the browser the list is deleted because it is no record of web users .. For now I still have the list of products in the cart and from any device is always the same and not cleared.

PD: I do not want to use `register/login` for users.. And the website where I am testing is;

Sorry I do not speak english really.
If someone do not understand, I can re-write it.
Regards.

Comment: What's your technical problem?

Comment: What SQL have you tried to achieve your expected result? Gotta show you've tried something before people will give you an answer.

Comment: If you're using a database to store cart data, you'll need to track which user is associated with which cart item. This can be difficult without using some kind of account/login system to differentiate users. Instead, I recommend using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store cart data.

Comment: @showdev Thanks, I'll have to use the method you said.. Do you know about some examples or info for my case? If you have the links paste it here please. Regards.

Comment: Here's [a bunch](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=php+build+a+cart+with+sessions). Here's the [first one](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/shopping-cart-in-php.html).

Comment: Newly thanks @showdev.. I am starting my proyect right now with the info you gave me. Regards